No puedo dar click a un botón con selenium
Usando selenium dentro de python estoy tratando de recolectar toda la información de precios que existe dentro de esta página: https://autos.aeromexico.com/reserva/CUN-CUN/2024-07-02_1430_2024-07-03_1430
Existen 2 botones para cambiar de página con la siguiente estructura
<li class="next"><a class="" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Next page" rel="next"><img src="/img/am_icons/arrow-right-solid.svg"></a></li>

<li><a rel="next" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Page 2">2</a></li>

Pero no logró hacer click a ninguno de estos para pasar a la siguiente página
Alguien podría ayudarme con esto

Al menos deberías añadir a la pregunta algo del código que has creado para poder darte alguna ayuda para tu problema. Por lo general, que no responda a clicks suele ser por no estar visibles o por no estar en foco. Si no tienes claro cómo está funcionando la web, prueba a grabar una sesión interactiva: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/getting-started
